# How to solve an equation with complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve an equation of a form
$ax^2$ ∠$θ - bx$ ∠$f - c = 0$,
thus, I have 3 complex parts:

1. magnitude of a complex number $ax^2$ with ∠$θ$ ($x$ is an unknown)
2. magnitude of a complex number $bx$ with ∠$f$ ($x$ and $f$ is unknown)
3. complex number c = ca+jcr (known)

There are two unknowns in this equation: $x$ (real number) and ∠$f$. Of course, it also can be rewritten as a system of equations

$ax^2 \cdot cos$∠$θ$ - $bx\cdot cos$∠$f$ - $ca$ = 0

$ax^2\cdot sin$∠$θ$ - $bx\cdot sin$∠$f$ - $cr$ = 0

where x and $∠$f are unknowns. x is a real number, $∠$f is an angle

Does anyone have a suggestion how it can be solved?

Comment: I don't really understand the notation here, are these "angle" variables just complex numbers with unit modulus, and $c$ is an arbitrary complex number? I also don't really understand what exactly is given and what isn't.

Comment: Hello! May you please edit your question with MathJax and provide the steps and methods you have tried to solve this problem? A guide to MathJax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1098096

Comment: How are MathSE reviewers supposed to provide help if they do not understand the Mathematical syntax that you are using?

Comment: @Ian, the variables are given in polar form in the first expression. There're 2 unknowns - x (in the magnitude of a complex number) and angle f (angle of the second complex number with the magnitude of b*x. c is a known complex number. c=ca+jcr

Comment: So $x$ is a nonnegative real number and $f$ is a real number in some interval of length $2\pi$ e.g. $[0,2\pi)$, right? And everything else is given? If I have that straight, you can first apply the quadratic formula to get $x$ and then examine the resulting expression to see what $f$ can be. (I also still don't really understand the relation between the number $b$ in the second term and the angle $b$ in the first term but it really doesn't matter.)

Comment: What do the angle signs mean?  Are they the argument of complex numbers?  You say "Of course, it also can be rewritten as a system of equations" when, of course it can not.  Equations about about the cos of an angle are  different than statements about the sin of the same angles and statements about the measure of angles are completely different.   Your question is very unclear and makes no sense.

Comment: just convert these phasors into a complex form. The first term is $\alpha_1=ax^2(\cos\theta+j\sin\theta)$ and the second term is $\alpha_2=bx(\cos f+j\sin f)$. The third term (i.e. $c=\alpha_3$) is already in the complex form. Now $\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is converting these phasors in a complex form. For the first and second terms, we get
$$
\begin{align}
ax^2\angle \theta &\implies \alpha_1 = ax^2(\cos\theta+j\sin \theta), \\
bx\angle f &\implies \alpha_2 = bx(\cos f+j\sin f). \\
\end{align}
$$
Let $c=d_1+jd_2$, we get

\begin{align}
[ax^2\cos\theta - bx\cos f -d_1] + j [ax^2\sin\theta - bx\sin f -d_2] = 0.
\end{align}
the above equation leads to
\begin{align}
ax^2\cos\theta - bx\cos f -d_1 &= 0, \\
ax^2\sin\theta - bx\sin f -d_2 &= 0.
\end{align}
which will eventually lead to a quadratic equation (*i.e.* by adding the two equations).

Comment: I agree. These two equations are indeed what I wrote in the question, but their solution leads to quartic equation, after sinf = (cosf^2-1)^0.5, not quadratic. Or if I go from the other end and find discremenants, I still get unknowns under the square roots and in quadrat .